# Second line of code executes before the first one C#

Tags: c#

I am using the following code. I want to navigate to a webpage and then click a button in the C# web browser control. However, even before I can navigate to the web page the click is invoked, causing a null exception.

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("www.remaxit.com/members"); // way before this
deleted = true;
HtmlDocument doc = this.webBrowser1.Document;
doc.GetElementById("AddUser").InvokeMember("CLICK"); //This executes
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Having never used the web browser tool in C#, I would wager that `Navigate` is non-blocking. You probably want to look for an event or something similar to `OnLoad`, and have your logic invoked after the page is loaded.

Answer (score 11):

The first line executes, however it does not finish loading the page before it runs the rest of the code.

Do something more like:

```
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);

void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    HtmlDocument doc = this.webBrowser1.Document;
    doc.GetElementById("AddUser").InvokeMember("CLICK");
}
```

This will fire your code off an event once the page finishes loading.

Comment: Is there any other way? Because I am using a timer condition to see if the timer is morning or evening. Depending on the time the webpage I navigate to will be different.

Comment: @CyraX6 You can just check some conditions in the event handler?